# Writing Control in Windows phone

Tags: c#, windows, custom-controls, windows-phone-7.1

I am trying to create a new Control (Let us for now forget about UserControl or CustomControl).

> I open a Windows phone Application project in vs2010 and then add a new item *Windows phone Control Library* and then I use it in my phone application.

Everything works fine. Now if I want to create a windows phone control to be used in another application how should I be going about it? New application means a separate new solution.

> Phone Application1 -> Have my own control inside the solution and hence I am able to use it.
>   How can I use this same control in another new solution?

I am not sure if this has been answered before. Does any solution already exist?

Cavet:
    I tried creating a new *Windows phone Class Library* in a vs2010 instance but it didn't work because it didn't had a xaml form. When I tried to manually include it and write the logic it build successfully but now even if I include the dll of this project I don't get the control in the toolbox. This process does not make much sense to me as I am creating a class library and not a control but still wanted to give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

To show controls from your assembly in the toolbox, you should do design-time assembly. You can look at these articles for the beginning:
[Link2](http://www.ningzhang.org/2009/11/30/silverlight-design-time-assemblies/)
[Link1](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/justinangel/archive/2008/11/17/silverlight-design-time-extensibility.aspx)
It's not easy and perhaps you can live without that if your control assembly is not a commercial product. To use any control from other assembly in application:

1. add project reference to your control assembly
2. include xmlns namespace attribute corresponding to your assembly to any page of your application. Just start typing 'xmlns=' near other xmlns definitions in the page header and VS intellisense will show you the list of available namespaces. Choose the needed one and then set namespace alias to use on the page. It should look something like  xmlns:myNamespace="clr-namespace:MyAssembly.Namespace.;assembly=MyAssembly"
3. insert control from your assembly into page using xaml editor
4. now you should be able to see your control in xaml designer and edit its properties from the property grid

.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the above mentioned method would solve the case, because as far as I have seen it is not possible to create a *Windows Phone Control Library* in VS2010. So this is what I did..

1. Created a *Windows Phone Control Library* and write my own custom control.
2. Build the project.
3. Back to Vs2010, added the reference to the control in the app in which I wish to use.

As simple as that. I don't know why it was initially a little bit confusing (perhaps I would have got confused with the binding and stuff). Anyways its quite simple though. Thank you for the reply.